# Call a toast event in the Lightning Web Component date selector

Tags: lightning-web-components, datetime, date, date-picker

Hi I have req where user select the date after the maximum date then i need to show the error toast message in saledforce LWC , can anyone help me out for the req.

Below is the code

```
let today = new Date()
let birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00')
let birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')
let birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17)            // the month is 0-indexed
let birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0)
```

Comment: Hi @Raman90, what problem you are facing here?

Comment: Hi rahul i just need to get the first date of the current month that will help me to solve the problem

Comment: do you want to get the first day of the selected month?

Comment: Yes that will help me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date value returned by change event is originally in string type. You need to convert that to date then you can simply use getMonth(), getYear() functions, and construct a new date which is the first day of the month.

```
handleDateChange(event) {
    if (event.detail.value) {
        let date = new Date(event.detail.value);
        let firstDayOfMonth = new Date(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
        console.log('first day of the month =>' + firstDayOfMonth);
    }
}
```

[Live playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/90vS3mxxs/2/edit).